# why onClickListener does not work in my fragment activity?

Tags: kotlin, onclicklistener

Im new in programming, and i got stuck with adding onClickListener in my FragmentHome.kt

i added this code to my existing activity:

```
val exc  = this.findViewById<Button>(R.id.execute)
    exc.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

I tried set onClicklistener on a blank activity and it worked, but when i added it to an existing
Fragment activity it does nothing (it should display a toast with some text)
I see no error messages so i don't know where the problem could be.

Thank you for your responses.

```
enter code here
public class FragmentHome : Fragment() {


public class HomeFragmentElements : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var spinView: Spinner


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home)


        val exc  = this.findViewById<Button>(R.id.execute)
        exc.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        
        

        spinView = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        spinView.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        }


    }
}

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)


    }


}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code into "onViewCreated":

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val exc  = this.findViewById<Button>(R.id.execute)
    exc.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

onViewCreated is executed after "onCreateView". View bindings and initializations should be into onViewCreated

Answer (score 0):

change the following in  your onCreateView

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    collectId(view)
            return view
    
    
        }

    fun collectId(view: view){
    val exc  = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.execute)
            exc.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }
```

You can consider viewBinding instead of findViewById

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have defined an AppCompatActivity subclass inside your Fragment class's definition, kind of like this:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment {

    class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

        //...
 
    }

}
```

The ability to define a non-`inner` class in a nested way is purely a code organization tool. There is absolutely no connection between your Fragment and Activity classes here. The code above is no different than if you did this, with each class in a completely different file:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment {

}

class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

}
```

It also doesn't make sense to think of an Activity as a child of a Fragment. A Fragment is a piece of an Activity, so it's the other way around.

All the code that you have in this Activity's `onCreate` should be put in the Fragment's `onViewCreated()` function, except for the call to `setContentView()`, because that's what your overriding of `onCreateView()` does. And remove the unused nested Activity class.

Also, you don't need to override `onCreateView` if you're simply inflating a layout and returning it. You can put the layout directly in the super-constructor call like this:

```
public class FragmentHome : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {

    private lateinit var spinView: Spinner

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // your view setup code

    }

}
```